# How to import external jars in a java ant project in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I am editing a java project which uses ant to build.

In one of my classes I import:

`import org.slf4j.Logger;`

`import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;`

And get the error `The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved`

In other projects I would add the file to a /lib folder and to the referenced libraries under Java Projects, but when I attempt to copy a jar file into my java project with ant I still have the error.

The jar for slf4j is in a lib folder but the import statement still doesn't recognize it. Is there a simple fix for this?

Do I have to add the jar file somewhere else?

Comment: What is your Java configuration in VS Code? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects

Answer (score 0):

Click the plus sign on the right side of **Referenced Libraries** under the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel to add a `.jar` package reference.

[image]

[Dependency-management](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management)